# iFrames in the iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, iframe, uiwebview, frames

So, I've got a webpage I'm trying to load in iPhone's Safari browser.  It all loads fine, except the iframe.  Ideally, the  iframe should be 200x200, and I'd like the user to be able to scroll around inside of it.

When I do this:

```
<iframe src="test.html" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

It seems to ignore the width and height attributes.

When I do this:

```
<iframe src="test.html" scrollable="no" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

then it seems to acknowledge the size attributes, but I can't scroll around within the frame, which is my ultimate goal.  I've also tried using CSS, such as:

```
.iframe {
  height:300px;
  width:280px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

to no avail (displays well, but still can't scroll around **inside** the iframe).

Would greatly appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: "Ideally, the iframe should be 200x200..." Ideally, there shouldn't *be* an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

iframes dont work like you think in mobile browsers.  On iOS you need to use 2 fingers to scroll an iframe.  It's not as seamless as it is on desktop browser.  You may need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Is this reflected in the simulator as well?  There it seems I can just drag the cursor.

Comment: I tried the two-finger scroll and it scrolls the whole page, not the iframe. Same thing as one-finger scroll.
EDIT: I see this was an answer from 2011. This might have been changed since then.

Comment: Mobile Safari has gotten an order magnitude better in regard to stuff like this.  So yeah, this may no longer be accurate.